# Not able to cross beyond my sql statement , the browser waits for something

Tags: javascript, html, sql, node.js

I am new to node js and js, My code is not able to cross the SQL statement

here is my app.js snippet for the SQL statement

my app.js

```
//declaration
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const fs = require('fs')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
var session = require('express-session');
const path = require('path')

app.use("/static", express.static('./static/'));

//For the body parser 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))

//parse the application Json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

// for the MySQL page 

var mysql = require('mysql')
var connection =  mysql.createConnection({

    host : 'localhost',
    user :  'root',
    password : '',
    database : 'login'
})

app.get ('/todo',(req,res)=>{

    res.writeHead(200,{'content-type' : 'text/html'})
    fs.createReadStream('project1.html').pipe(res)

  })

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000)
```

my todo.js

```
document.addEventListener('submit',myFunction)
 function myFunction(e){
    
  console.log("in the data post method")
  let sql = 'INSERT INTO `acc` (`name`) VALUES (?)'  
    connection.query(sql,req.body.name,(error,result)=>{
        if(error) throw error
        console.log('value inserted')
        connection.end();
  })
    e.preventDefault();
    var text = document.querySelector("input").value; 
    var text = document.querySelector("input").value;
    var node = document.createElement("p");
    node.id="li1"
   
    if (text!=""){

                    var textnode=document.createTextNode(text);
                    node.appendChild(textnode); //append the value to LI  
                    text = document.getElementById("demo")
                    console.log(text) ;
                    document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(node); //append the value to UI
                    document.querySelector("input").value = ""
 
                   
                }
    // document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener('mouseover',myFunction1)
                str = document.getElementById("li1")
                console.log(str)
}  

//SELECTING AN ELEMENT THAT WAS CREATAED DYNAMICALLY AND APPLLY SOME PROPERTY
  $(document).on('click','p',function(){
    $(this).css({"text-decoration": "line-through",color : "pink" });
    $(this).fadeOut(1500);
    // $(this).remove();
   
  })
```

my project1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Create a table</title>
 
    <script src="./static/todo.js"></script>
    
</head>

<body>
    <h1>ToDo</h1>
    <form  id="form" action="/data" method="post">
        <input type="text" name = "name" class="input" id="tt">
    </form>
    
        <div id= "lip">
            <ul id="demo" id="demo">
                    
                    
            </ul>
        </div>
   
</body>
</html>
```

I want to insert the user typed value in the database as well as I have to list them in the front end, both codes work separately but when I combine them, after executing the SQL statement the browser waits for something

Please help me.

Comment: I don't really know Node, but sql queries seem to be a server-side issue, while that document stuff is browser-side. So I don't think you can mix them

Comment: If your goal is to get requests from your server by using SQL, maybe [PHP](https://www.php.net/) would be a better choice, coupled with [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) requests.

Comment: Hard to tell without a complete / working test case.  The above seems to show only one SQL statement and that closes the connection when completed.  Can you show the rest of the complete test case?

Comment: basically, I want to build a todo app that will display both the user input in UI and add it in a database, if I remove my database query it perfectly displays the item that the user types in the text field but when I add SQL part it only add it in the database without displaying it in the UI, I will put my all my code in the question for your complete reference.